# Add a key to an object with keys of an existing array with objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

I've got an array of objects `array = [object1, object2, ...]`, each of them has some keys `object1 = { key1: 'value1', ... }`. I want to add a key this way:

```
$rootScope.array[i].newKey = 'someValue'
```

But angular tells me that `$rootScope.array[i]` is `undefined`.

What I've noticed from console is that the objects get the new key but the console still says the same.

Comment: did you add the array to your `$rootScope` ? like `$rootScope.array = array;`

Comment: yes actually I do `$rootScope.meatTypes = [{}];`

Comment: this means that meat types is an array that contains one empty object. To declare an empty array just use `$rootScope.meatTypes = []`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use **less than** and not **less or equal than** comparator.

```
  $scope.init = function () {
        for (i = 0; i < /* not <= */ $rootScope.meatTypes.length; i++) {
            console.log("I am showing the meatypes:");
            console.log($rootScope.meatTypes);
            $rootScope.meatTypes[i].counter = '0';
            counterOperations.setCounters(i, 0);
        }
        $rootScope.total = 0;
        counterOperations.setTopCounter(0);
    };
```

because when `i` equals `$rootScope.meatTypes.length` then `$rootScope.meatTypes[i]` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access a member of the array that does not exist.

You need to create a new object and push it onto the array:

```
$rootScope.array.push({'key1': 'someValue'});
```

Comment: I need to create a new key in an existing object of my array not to create a new object.

Comment: When I actually do this my browser crashes:
` $scope.init = function () {
        for (i = 0; i <= $rootScope.meatTypes.length; i++) {
            console.log("I am showing the meatypes:");
            console.log($rootScope.meatTypes);
            $rootScope.meatTypes.push({'counter':0});          
            counterOperations.setCounters(i, 0);
        }
        $rootScope.total = 0;
        counterOperations.setTopCounter(0);
    }; `

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention [lodash](https://lodash.com/), but when I see someone encounter an issue like this, I want to offer the recommendation of using lodash (or underscore.js).

With lodash, you would do something like so, using [_.set](https://lodash.com/docs#set), which defensively protects against your described issue by *automatically* adding the necessary elements in the path:

```
_.set($rootScope, ['array', i, 'newKey'], 'someValue');
```

This library, properly utilized, solves *many* issues that you can have with setting and getting variables, ase well as other super useful tools. It has been a major life-saver (and time-saver) for us on our projects.

Answer (score 0):

Like this you can add

```
$rootScope.array[i] = {}; // first we should create an object on that array location
$rootScope.array[i]['newKey'] = 'someValue'; // then only we can add values
```

**EDIT:**

```
$scope.init = function () {
    for (i = 0; i <= $rootScope.meatTypes.length; i++) {
        console.log("I am showing the meatypes:");
        console.log($rootScope.meatTypes);
        **// This is needed**
        $rootScope.meatTypes[i]={};// here we should tell that metaType[newItem] is an object other wise it treat it as undefined
        $rootScope.meatTypes[i].counter = '0';
        counterOperations.setCounters(i, 0);
    }
    $rootScope.total = 0;
    counterOperations.setTopCounter(0);
};
```